# Is there a way of segmenting listview items A - Z

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I've been looking for an answer to this quesion online for sometime and not yet managed to find a suitable answer.

I have a listview which displays suppliers in alphabetical order. However, what I want to achieve is a definite split, sort of like this:

A's

A Supplier 1
A Supplier 2

B's

B Supplier 1
B Supplier 2

I think this is possible using nested repeaters - but is there a way of doing this with the listview control?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you use a `<HeaderTemplate>`?

Comment: I don't know - I'll look into it, but I will need multiple headers - one for each letter of the alphabet

Comment: You would group by the first letter of your suppliers and use that as the group key. So `Key: A, Value: [A supplier, A suppler 2...]` etc... bind your list view to this datasource. Then in the repeating header section, set a label/whatever to the groups key, in the repeating item section, list out your suppliers. Something like that...

Comment: I'm sure what you're saying makes sense, I just can't understand it enough to move forward. Is there any further info you can provide?

Comment: Upon further reflection, I'm pretty sure `ListView` doesn't have a `<HeaderTemplate>` unfortunately. But the basic code to do the grouping is something like: `listOfSuppliers.GroupBy(x => x.SupplierName[0]).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());` this would group by the first letter in the supplier name. You could then order this by `Key` ascending to get a nice `A, B, C` ordering. Is there a specific reason why you can't use an `<asp:Repeater />`? It would be incredibly easy to set up VS doing this with a `ListView`.